# Are there any setuid/setguid bits in OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, setuid

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Are there anything like this under OpenBSD?

Answer (score 6):

[Yes, of course.](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=setuid&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html) It's [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/setuid.html). (And there're more, also non-standard, [security features in OpenBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD_security_features).)

(If you meant "are there any files with these bits *set*", try `find / -type f \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000\) -print`)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know Dennis Ritchie got a patent for suid/sgid (placed in the public domain; would have expired by how anyway)

Comment: I'm just asking because of this for ex.: http://blog.zx2c4.com/749 - so there could be security bugs regarding SUID bits. Couldn't they be turned off??